# how to let nav menu overflow on main div

Tags: html, css, navbar

I created basic html page with horizontal menu with submenu in nav.
I would like to allow submenu open and be usable at main area, but nav resizes moving main down.
I tried overflow options, but without success (no effetcs). I tried absolute position for main,but then submenu cannot be used (when I move cursor to submenu it disappears), although it is shown as I wish. Code below. Thanks for answers.

```css
header {
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  border-radius: 1px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px;
  width: 1480px;
  height: 70px;
}

nav.horizontal {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 1480px;
  height: 50px;
  resize: none;
}

main {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 1480px;
  height: 600px;
}

nav.horizontal>li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}

nav.horizontal>li>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav.horizontal li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

nav.horizontal>li>ul>a {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(255, 255, 0), rgb(255, 255, 0));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(150deg, rgbrgb(255, 255, 0), rgb(255, 255, 0));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(255, 255, 0), rgb(255, 255, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(255, 255, 0), rgb(255, 255, 0));
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  font-size: .65rem;
  width: 180px;
  height: 30px;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav.horizontal>li>a {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 5);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(255, 255, 5));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(255, 255, 5));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(255, 255, 5));
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(255, 255, 5));
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  font-size: .85rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 211px;
  height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav.horizontal>li>a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(114, 51, 98);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Title</header>
  <nav class="horizontal">
    <li>
      <a href="#"> Menu </a>
      <ul>
        <a href="#">First</a>
        <a href="#">Second</a>
        <a href="#">Third</a>
        <a href="#">Fourth</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </nav>
  <main>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: please attach screenshot the menu seems working fine: https://prnt.sc/iaazvb

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your `nav.horizontal > li > ul` (subnav)

```
position: absolute;
```

Be safe and use `ul & li` always like:

```
<ul>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

You can always check your Markup [here (https://validator.w3.org/)](https://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Since [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) states that

> The HTML `<li>` element is used to represent an item in a list. It must be contained in a parent element: an ordered list (`<ol>`), an unordered list (`<ul>`), or a menu (`<menu>`).

I would wrap the `<li>` inside `nav.horizontal` in `<ul>` and then add correct positioning (`position: relative;` for the parent and `position: absolute;` for the child). Also in your case you might like to set parent's paddings&margins to 0. Check it out:

```css
header {
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
  border-radius: 1px;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:1px;
  width: 1480px;
  height: 70px;
}
nav.horizontal {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 1480px;
  height: 50px;
  resize:none;
}
main {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 1480px;
  height: 600px;
}
nav.horizontal > ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav.horizontal > ul > li {  // our parent element
     list-style-type: none;
     float: left;
     position: relative;
}
nav.horizontal > ul > li > ul {  // our child elemnt
     list-style-type: none;
     display:none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 100%;
}
nav.horizontal ul li:hover > ul  {
  display: block;
}
nav.horizontal > ul > li > ul > a {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(255, 255, 0), rgb(255, 255, 0));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(150deg, rgbrgb(255, 255, 0), rgb(255, 255, 0));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(255, 255, 0), rgb(255, 255, 0));
    background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(255, 255, 0), rgb(255, 255, 0));
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    display: block;
    font-size: .65rem;
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all .1s ease;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
nav.horizontal > ul > li > a {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 5);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(255, 255, 5));
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(255, 255, 5));
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(255, 255, 5));
        background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(255, 255, 5));
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        color: rgb(255,255,255);
        display: block;
        font-size: .85rem;
        font-weight: 500;
        width: 211px;
        height: 50px;
        letter-spacing: .1rem;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        text-transform: uppercase;
        transition: all .1s ease;
        text-decoration: none;
}

nav.horizontal > ul > li > a:hover {
        background-color: rgb(114, 51, 98);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
        background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
        cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>Title</header>
    <nav class="horizontal">  
    <ul>
            <li>
                <a href = "#"> Menu </a>
            <ul>
                <a href="#">First</a>
                <a href="#">Second</a>
            <a href="#">Third</a>
            <a href="#">Fourth</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
    </main>
    <footer> 
    </footer>
```